# install python 3.6 from source, now dpkg is messed up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, dpkg

I installed 3.6 from source to /opt in Ubuntu 16.04 thinking that I was avoiding startnig any python conflicts this way.

Next time I tried to run `apt-get update` I ran into an error that says...

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
...
```

when I run `apt-get -f install` I see a warning saying that a lot of stuff is going to be removed...

when I run `apt-cache policy python` I see this...

```
python:
  Installed: 3.6.0-1
  Candidate: 3.6.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.0-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.11-1 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

So my questions...

1. Why would installing from source (to `/opt`) interfere with dpkg?
2. How can I get dpkg to forget about my python3.6 install
3. I don't want to remove a lot of stuff that I need on the system, so other than making dpkg forget about python3, what can I do?

Comment: How did you install Python 3.6 from source? It seems you somehow ended up installing a `python` 3.6 package.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt i am not sure actually. it is poosible that I built a deb package at some point but I dont remember. dpkg remove doesnt work so I have no idea how it got there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Installing purely from source wouldn't interfere with `dpkg`, you must have somehow installed a package at some point.
2. You need to re-install the `python` package:

   ```
   apt-get --reinstall install python=2.7.11-1
   ```

   This should restore your Python setup and stop asking you to remove lots of packages. You'll probably need to re-install Python 3.6 in `/opt`, *from source* without a package.
3. See above.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove python 3.6 you installed then try [LinuxBrew](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew)  It will install python and many other software to your own home directory. It won't conflict with python on your system.

I use LinuxBrew on all my Linux boxes including VMs.

Thanks